# Is there a way to convert images embed in a pdf from jpg/gif/whatever to png or gif?

Tags: pdf, compression, png, jpeg, ghostscript

the biggest part of the question is in the title...

I have big pdf files made from concatenated scanned documents which are something like press articles: text+images. The important part is the text, not the pictures...

That's why I thought (accordingly to this [article](https://litmus.com/blog/png-gif-or-jpeg-which-ones-should-you-use-in-email)) to compress all the images in the pdf to png or gif...

Thanks for all your propositions, I already spend too much time to try optimize my ghostscript command line options :-p

FYI that my current ghostscript 9.14 command line in production :

```
gs -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
   -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dQUIET -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook \
   -dColorImageResolution=150 -dGrayImageResolution=150 -dMonoImageResolution=800 \
   -dPreserveOPIComments=false -dPreserveOverprintSettings=false \
   -dUCRandBGInfo=/Remove -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceRGB -dMaxInlineImageSize=0 \
   -dDetectDuplicateImages=true -dFastWebView=false -dUseFlateCompression=true \
   -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false -dAutoFilterColorImages=false \
   -dColorImageDownsampleThreshold=1.2 \
   -sOUTPUTFILE=/tmp/screen_20140602103745.pdf \
   -c "512000000 setvmthreshold /QFactor 0.80 /Blend 1 /ColorTransform 1 /HSamples [2 1 1 2] /VSamples [2 1 1 2]" \
   -f /usr/bases/dicodrp/pdf/pdf_concatenes/20140602103745.pdf
```

I got about 40% compression and something *just readable*, but I think I can improve the readibility just in changing the image compression type (I got that noisy jpg artifacts...)

No, I can't increase the dpi because that will increase the file size... :-)

Comment: Only FYI: PDF does not *literally* support either PNG or GIF. Bitmap images may be compressed in a PNG-like manner (that is, with row filters and LZW compression), but it's not as if it would *not* do this if you don't specifically specify it.

Comment: Oooh, I see... It will be difficult to increase text readibility like that then :-(

Do you have any idea on how can I improve the readibility without increasing the file size?

Comment: Hi-res monochrome scans, or grayscale or RGB? If one of the latter, you might increase the contrast.

Comment: most of them are RGB, i'll try increase contrast ;-)

Comment: I wonder if PDF would handle "BitsPerComponent", if so you could set the RGB to use 4 bits per color, rather than 8 bits per channel, which "in theory" could cut the file in half.

Comment: @Jongware: I searched a long time yesterday on "how can I customize the contrast with GS" vainly...

Comment: @FredF: As I read in the documentation, BitsPerComponent seems to be an option only if I expect to export as tiff :-p